# How to run tests before the commit in Pycharm/Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, pre-commit-hook

Is it possible to run a specified script before any commit in Pycharm/Intellij Idea? I want to make sure that tests are not broken.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/):

- [Pre-Tested Commit: No broken code in your version control](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/delayed_commit.html)

Note that it also provides integration with IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to setup team city for my project.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, which is how to enable this in PyCharm/IDEA.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to buy a TeamCity licence, you can also use the ["toggle auto-test"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/test-runner-tab.html) feature that re-runs your tests whenever you change them.

It does not block your commits but warns you when you have a failed test.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a similar quick solution, I integrated test execution before launch project execution adding a item in **Run/Debug configuration - Before launch**

Another best solution is integrate a git hook client like [pre-commit](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit)